# How can i print an array index defined in different class in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, printing, echo

I am trying to reach and print every index of an array in different places. The array defined in a different function of a class named namaz like:

```
public function vakitler($sehir, $cikti = 'array') {
     $sonuc = array(
         'durum' => 'hata',
         'veri' => array()
      );
      $yer = $this->_yerBilgisi($sehir);
      $cacheDosyasi = "cache_" . $yer['sehir_id'] . ".ndb";
      $sunucu = $this->_sunucudanVeriCek($yer['url']);
      if($sunucu['durum'] == 'basarili' && count($sunucu['veri']['vakitler']) > 0) {
         $icerik = array(
            'ulke' => $yer['ulke'],
            'sehir' => $yer['sehir'],
            'ilce' => $yer['ilce'],
            'yer_adi' => $yer['uzun_adi'],
            'vakitler' => $sunucu['veri']['vakitler']
         );
         $sonuc['durum'] = 'basarili';
         $sonuc['veri'] = $icerik;
        $this->_cacheYaz($cacheDosyasi, json_encode($sonuc));
      }
     return ($cikti == 'array' ? $sonuc : json_encode($sonuc));
    }
```

and here is the class which gets information from other website to fill vakitler function

```
private function _htmlOku($veri) {
      $sonuc = array(
         'vakitler' => array()
      );

      if(strpos($veri, "<div id = \"tab-1\" class=\"w3-container w3-border nv-tab-content\" style=\"display:none\">") !== FALSE) {
         $bolme1 = explode("<div id = \"tab-1\" class=\"w3-container w3-border nv-tab-content\" style=\"display:none\">", $veri);
         $elimizde_kalan = explode("</section>", $bolme1[1]);
         $html = str_get_html($elimizde_kalan[0]);

         foreach ($html->find('tr') as $tr) {
            $sira = 0;
            $simdikiSatir = "";

            foreach ($tr->find('td') as $td) {
               $elde = trim($td->plaintext);

               if($sira == 0) {
                  $tarih = $this->_kisaTarih($elde);
                  $sonuc['vakitler'][$tarih] = array(
                     'tarih' => $tarih,
                     'tarih_uzun' => $elde,
                     'hicri' => $this->_hicriTarih($tarih),
                     'hicri_uzun' => $this->_hicriTarih($tarih, true),
                     'imsak' => '',
                     'gunes' => '',
                     'ogle' => '',
                     'ikindi' => '',
                     'aksam' => '',
                     'yatsi' => ''
                  );
                  $simdikiSatir = $tarih;
               }     
               if($sira == 1) {
                  $sonuc['vakitler'][$simdikiSatir]['imsak'] = $elde;
               }
               if($sira == 2) {
                  $sonuc['vakitler'][$simdikiSatir]['gunes'] = $elde;
               }
               if($sira == 3) {
                  $sonuc['vakitler'][$simdikiSatir]['ogle'] = $elde;
               }
               if($sira == 4) {
                  $sonuc['vakitler'][$simdikiSatir]['ikindi'] = $elde;
               }
               if($sira == 5) {
                  $sonuc['vakitler'][$simdikiSatir]['aksam'] = $elde;
               }
               if($sira == 6) {
                  $sonuc['vakitler'][$simdikiSatir]['yatsi'] = $elde;
               }
               $sira++;
            }
            $sira = 0;
         } 
         $html->clear();
      } 
      return $sonuc;
   }
```

after saving these functions in a class and try to reach only one index in array with:

```
$namaz = new Namaz();
$vakitler = $namaz->vakitler(9206); //9206 the place where i want to see results
print_r($vakitler);
```

the result is like [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssLYO.jpg)

I want to reach every array differently and show them in some other places.
for example i want to print `echo $vakitler['ikindi']` in a tab of a table and `$vakitler['aksam']` in different tab. How can i print different array values in different places? I will be glad for your answers.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You already see the structure of the array there, it seems you get all the information in it that you need, what stops you from doing what you just wrote, putting `echo $vakitler['ikindi']` in the place where you render the first table, and `echo $vakitler['aksam']` in the second?

Comment: When i write echo $vakitler('ikindi'); it says  Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in index.php:49 Stack trace: #0 {main}

Comment: Do you see the difference between what you just wrote and what you wrote before? `$vahitler('ikindi')` is a function call (wrong), `$vahitler['ikindi']` is an array index access (correct)...

Comment: sorry you are right. I noticed that after i posted here and I wrote echo $vakitler['ikindi'] and it says Undefined index.

Comment: OK sorry I didn't fully look at the structure before. It's right, there is no `ikindi` index at the top level. Which index are you trying to access? There are several called `ikindi`. For example: `$vakitler['veri']['vakitler']['18.04.2020']['ikindi']`, `$vakitler['veri']['vakitler']['19.04.2020']['ikindi']`, `$vakitler['veri']['vakitler']['20.04.2020']['ikindi']`, etc.

Comment: Maybe you want to take the date index from a variable instead... like `$vakitler['veri']['vakitler'][$date]['ikindi']` for example, but then of course you'd need to define `$date` beforehand to whatever you need. (For example: `$date = date('Y.m.d');` for current date)

Comment: Thank you @CherryDT it worked. Thank you very much. echo $vakitler['veri']['vakitler']['20.04.2020']['ikindi']